# Do I need to create partitions in advance for Kubuntu installation if I have unallocated space?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, kubuntu

I am working on installing Kubuntu to dual boot on a WinXP laptop.

I have 86MB Unallocated, (C:) 73GB NTFS (System), Files (D:) 175GB NTFS, and I have created 50GB Unallocated (unformated) space at the end of the HDD.

Do I need to partition and format that space in advance of the installation or will Kubuntu do this during the installation?

Comment: I would have guessed that this was a dead simple question for anyone that had a clue about the whole thing -- or maybe it was too simple. Since I couldn't get an answer here or find it anywhere else, I kamikazed into the installation. I survived, and for any poor ignorant soul like myself that might be looking for an answer to the same question, I might as well answer it myself.

Answer (score 1):

Kubuntu will recognise the unallocated space and will give you the possibility during the installation to partition it further, to allow space for your swap file.